# Portable.Licensing - saving license to file

Tags: c#

I'm trying to save the license to a file like so:

```
File.WriteAllText(theSaveFileDialogBox.FileName, license.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8);
```

as suggested here:

http://dev.nauck-it.de/projects/portable-licensing/wiki/GettingStarted

But the contents of my save file always end up being just

> Portable.Licensing.LicenseBuilder

As if the `ToString()` method wasn't overridden.  Also, the `Save()` method doesn't even appear as a member of `license`.  Any ideas?

**Update:**

The problem was I was trying to build the license up by parts, as such:

```
var license = Portable.Licensing.License.New().WithUniqueIdentifier(Guid.NewGuid());

if (lic_type_box.Text == "Trial") license.As(LicenseType.Trial);
else if (lic_type_box.Text == "Full") license.As(LicenseType.Standard);

int days;
if (int.TryParse(lic_days.Text, out days)) license.ExpiresAt(DateTime.Now.AddDays(days));    
if (lic_name.Text != "") license.LicensedTo("lic_name.Text", "");  
license.CreateAndSignWithPrivateKey(privateKey, passPhrase);
```

when the last line should really have been

```
var createdLicense = license.CreateAndSignWithPrivateKey(privateKey, passPhrase);
```

and then

```
File.WriteAllText(theSaveFileDialogBox.FileName, createdLicense.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never actually used this library however `Portable.Licensing.LicenseBuilder` is (probably) what is the result of `license.ToString()`.

Looking at their tutorial they are actually calling the method `CreateAndSignWithPrivateKey(..,...)` which is a method that returns back an instance of `License` not `LicenseBuilder`.

This is key as the `License` class overrides the `ToString()` method and returns the xml data produced from the result of the license builder class.

Right so this seems a bit complex but basically `License.New()` returns an `ILicenseBuilder`. This does not have a `Save` method but `License` does.\

[License.cs](https://github.com/dnauck/Portable.Licensing/blob/develop/src/Portable.Licensing/License.cs)

[LicenseBuilder](https://github.com/dnauck/Portable.Licensing/blob/develop/src/Portable.Licensing/LicenseBuilder.cs)

Now thats about as much as we can help you with as you will need to provide us some code as to what exactly `license` is.

Comment: Wow, great job debugging.  Thank you - I didn't realize the `CreateAndSignWithPrivateKey()` method was returning a new object.

Comment: Sorry the answer is a bit tough to follow.. sort of my brain dump while navigating github and their tutorials. Glad its sorted.